# Difference in values returned from C++ and Python calling the same underlying LAPACK wrapper

Tags: python, c++, scipy, linear-algebra, lapack

I've been converting some C++ code to Python (for ease of use for myself) but I've found an issue I'm unnable to make sense of.

The C++ code calls the [DGESVD function](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d7e/group__double_g_esing_ga84fdf22a62b12ff364621e4713ce02f2.html) from the linear algebra LAPACK library, to calculate singular value decomposition of an array.

The [Scipy Python library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html) wraps the LAPACK functions and I can select the same underlying LAPACK driver used in the C++ code (DGESVD).

For smaller array sizes the values I get back in both C++ and Python match, but beyond a certain size array the first column or two of returned values match, but after that they don't.

In the C++ code I'm converting the ratio between number of rows and columns is 316 columns for each 1 row.

If I use 5 rows and 1,580 columns the returned values from C++ and Python match. If I use 6 rows and 1,896 columns things start to fall apart.

Minimum repeatable example code for both C++ and Python below. The returned array of interest is 'u'.

The DGESVD function in C++ takes a 1D fortran array (column-major), where as the Python implementation takes a 2D numpy array (row-major), which is why I flatten the array returned from Python to compare to the output of the C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// dgesvd_ is a symbol in the LAPACK library files
extern "C" {
    extern void dgesvd_(char* jobu, char* jobvt, int* m, int* n, double* A,
        int* lda, double* S, double* U, int* ldu, double* VT,
        int* ldvt, double* work, int* lwork, int* info);
}

int main() {
    int m = 6; // Number of rows of the matrix A
    int n = 1896; // Number of columns of the matrix A
    int size = n * m;

    double* a, vt, *work;

    a = (double*)malloc(m * n * sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        a[i] = 19;
    }

    int lda = m; // Leading dimension of the array A

    std::vector<double> s(std::min(m, n)); // Vector to store the singular values

    int ldu = m; // Leading dimension of the array U
    std::vector<double> u(ldu * m); // Array to store the left singular vectors U

    int ldvt = 1; // Leading dimension of the array VT
    vt = NULL;

    int lwork = m * 5; // Optimal work array size query flag
   
    int info; // Output info flag

    work = (double*)malloc(lwork * sizeof(double));

    double work_query; // Variable to query optimal work array size

    char save[] = "S", nosave[] = "N";

    // Compute the SVD
    dgesvd_(save, nosave, &m, &n, a, &lda, s.data(), u.data(), &ldu, &vt, &ldvt, work, &lwork, &info);

    // Check for successful computation
    if (info > 0) {
        std::cerr << "SVD computation failed: " << info << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int array_length;
    array_length = m * m;

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("svd_testing.csv");

    // for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++)
    {
        // print first column's element
        outfile << u.data()[i];

        // print newline between rows
        outfile << endl;
    }

    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import svd

m = 6
n = 1896
a = np.ones((m, n))
a = a * 19
u, s, v = svd(a, full_matrices=False, lapack_driver='gesvd')

u0 = u.flatten('F')
np.savetxt('u0_python_test.csv', u0)
```

Comment: IIRC, _U_ and _V_ matrices are not determined uniquely. Is it possible that C++ program uses a different LAPACK implementation than Python?